# Having trouble saving an existing word document

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-automation

I'm trying to save an existing docx file on the desktop after I automate the word document in C#. I'm using the window form to execute my application. I'm able to save the document when there's no same file name exists on the desktop. However when I try to save the same file name again it will give me this error message:

> You cannot save while the file is in use by another process. Try
>   saving the file with a new name. (C:...\Desktop\TempWord.docx)

I read it in the [Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192495%28v=office.11%29.aspx)  I'm able to use SaveAs if there's an existing file name, it will automatically override it.

I'm not too sure why this kind of message appears because I did not open any other word document at all when this program is being run.

I'm not too sure how to resolve this problem. Maybe I did something very stupid that I did not see :(

---

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection; 
using Microsoft.Office;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace TestWordAutoWithTemplate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void butGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //OBJECT OF MISSING "NULL VALUE"
            Object oMissing = Missing.Value;

            //OBJECTS OF FALSE AND TRUE
            Object oTrue = true;
            Object oFalse = false;

            //CREATING OBJECTS OF WORD AND DOCUMENT
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();

            //SETTING THE VISIBILITY TO TRUE
            //oWord.Visible = true;

            //THE LOCATION OF THE TEMPLATE FILE ON THE MACHINE
            Object oTemplatePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\YYC\Desktop\TestTemplate.dotx";

            //ADDING A NEW DOCUMENT FROM A TEMPLATE
            oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            int iTotalFields = 0; 

            foreach (Word.Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)
            {
                iTotalFields++;
                Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
                String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

                // ONLY GETTING THE MAILMERGE FIELDS
                if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
                {
                    // THE TEXT COMES IN THE FORMAT OF
                    // MERGEFIELD  MyFieldName  \\* MERGEFORMAT
                    // THIS HAS TO BE EDITED TO GET ONLY THE FIELDNAME "MyFieldName"
                    Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                    Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                    String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);

                    // GIVES THE FIELDNAMES AS THE USER HAD ENTERED IN .dot FILE
                    fieldName = fieldName.Trim();

                    // **** FIELD REPLACEMENT IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE ****//
                    // THE PROGRAMMER CAN HAVE HIS OWN IMPLEMENTATIONS HERE
                    if (fieldName == "Name")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        //Check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtName.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtName.Text); 
                        }
                    }
                    if (fieldName == "Address")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        //Check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtAddress.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtAddress.Text);
                        }
                    }

                    if (fieldName == "Age")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        // check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtAge.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtAge.Text); 
                        }
                    }

                    if (fieldName == "EAddress")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        // check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtEmail.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtEmail.Text);
                        }
                    }

                    if (fieldName == "Company")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        // Check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtCompany.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtCompany.Text);
                        }
                    }

                    if (fieldName == "TelNo")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        // Check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtTelephone.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtCompany.Text);
                        }
                    }

                    if (fieldName == "ODetails")
                    {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        // Check whether the control text is empty
                        if (txtOther.Text == "")
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtOther.Text);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            oWord.Visible = false;

            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordDoc.Fields);
            //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordDoc);
            //Marshal.;


            // If you want your document to be saved as docx
            Object savePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\YYC\Desktop\TempWord.doc";
            //oWordDoc.Save();
            oWordDoc.SaveAs(ref savePath
                //, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing, 
                //ref oMissing
               );



            // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
            // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the 
            // correct Close method. 
            object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            ((Word._Document)oWordDoc).Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            oWordDoc = null; 
            // word has to be case to type _Application so that it will find 
            // the correct Quit method. 
            ((Word._Application)oWord).Quit(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            oWord = null;
            GC.Collect();


        }
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure where I did it wrong.

Edit: I put the original code in.

Comment: Have you tried doing just Save?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, but I need to save it to a file name.

Comment: What does the error message say.. also when you dispose of ComObjects via Microsoft.Office.Interop you need to Dispose of them using the Marshal.ReleaseComObject( oWord) for example

Comment: @DJKRAZE This is the error messsage: You cannot save while the file is in use by another process. Try saving the file with a new name.
 (C:\...\Desktop\TempWord.docx)

Comment: This is not specific to word and very general every time you wirte any file on a disk : "You cannot save while the file is in use by another process". This simply means there is a Handler created somehow to "take hand" on the existing file before having to save it "as" (i.e) copying it. This probably happens because your "save as" process is trying to acces the file in write mode even if it is just to copy it. I guess you need to make sure your file is freed from any resource before trying to save it "as".

Comment: Also, before all, as `yyc2001` pointed out make sure to use another name than the actual name of the present file. Perhaps that's enough

Comment: @MikaJacobi is there any way to freed the resource before trying to save the document

Comment: in your Object missing = Missing.Value, does that reference the System.Reflection.Missing.Value; if not declare the Object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Comment: To free a ComObject you have to System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( yourObject );

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes I double checked it. "Missing.Value" is referencing the " System.Reflection.Missing.Value;" I just put it into using instead of typing everything out.

Comment: also where you have in your foreach loop word.Field is it the same as if you were to replace it with foreach(Field in ....) ?

Comment: I also just noticed something shouldn't your         //SETTING THE VISIBILITY TO TRUE         oWord.Visible = true; be set true after you loop thru and set the field(s) value..???

Comment: @DJKRAZE Actually I'm very new at word automation. I start to learn this yesterday. I'm so sorry for all the mistake I make.

Comment: Mistakes are no issue we all make them .. just trying to help you out.. anyone who says that they have never made a mistake is not human..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I found something very interesting while I was trying to solve the problem. The template is in dotx format and the file I save is in docx; will this make the program think I'm using the document. After I change the save file to doc format it will not give me any errors. It's kind of weird. However, I really want to know why I cannot save the file in docx format.

Comment: what version of word do you have on your machine.. normally if there is a .docx file ext and your version is a lower version it will convert to a .doc.. here is something I would suggest doing to see if the .SaveAs works.. first comment out the Template code and run the code to see if it saves.. also can you edit your original post and paste in the full Code so that I can see how you have things truly defined and setup? it's hard to really see what you really have via your original code sample

Comment: @DJKRAZE Currently, I'm using Microsoft Office 2007. I will post all the code.

Comment: the ext should work .docx humm

Comment: @DJKRAZE I put in the whole code.

Comment: I am going to test your code now..

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine for me I made some changes as well I would like to know when you debug this .. does it jump out of your for loop right away..? if so there is a problem but it should still create a copy of a TempWord.doc for you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7509/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-yyc2001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a method out of this so place this line of Code get rid of it in button generate and copy the new method below so your new code should look like this

```
private void butGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SaveWordTemp2WordDoc();      
}

public void SaveWordTemp2WordDoc()
{
    //OBJECT OF MISSING "NULL VALUE"
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    //OBJECTS OF FALSE AND TRUE
    Object oTrue = true;
    Object oFalse = false;

    //CREATING OBJECTS OF WORD AND DOCUMENT
    Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();

    //SETTING THE VISIBILITY TO TRUE
    //oWord.Visible = true;

    //THE LOCATION OF THE TEMPLATE FILE ON THE MACHINE
    //Change the path to a path like c:\files\docTemps\
    Object oTemplatePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\YYC\Desktop\TestTemplate.dotx";

    //ADDING A NEW DOCUMENT FROM A TEMPLATE
    oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    int iTotalFields = 0;

    foreach (Word.Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)
    {
        iTotalFields++;
        Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
        String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

        // ONLY GETTING THE MAILMERGE FIELDS
        if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
        {
            // THE TEXT COMES IN THE FORMAT OF
            // MERGEFIELD  MyFieldName  \\* MERGEFORMAT
            // THIS HAS TO BE EDITED TO GET ONLY THE FIELDNAME "MyFieldName"
            Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
            Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
            String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);

            // GIVES THE FIELDNAMES AS THE USER HAD ENTERED IN .dot FILE
            fieldName = fieldName.Trim();

            // **** FIELD REPLACEMENT IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE ****//
            // THE PROGRAMMER CAN HAVE HIS OWN IMPLEMENTATIONS HERE
            if (fieldName == "Name")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                //Check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtName.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtName.Text);
                }
            }
            if (fieldName == "Address")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                //Check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtAddress.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtAddress.Text);
                }
            }

            if (fieldName == "Age")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                // check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtAge.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtAge.Text);
                }
            }

            if (fieldName == "EAddress")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                // check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtEmail.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtEmail.Text);
                }
            }

            if (fieldName == "Company")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                // Check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtCompany.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtCompany.Text);
                }
            }

            if (fieldName == "TelNo")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                // Check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtTelephone.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtCompany.Text);
                }
            }

            if (fieldName == "ODetails")
            {
                myMergeField.Select();
                // Check whether the control text is empty
                if (txtOther.Text == "")
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(txtOther.Text);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    oWord.Visible = false;

    // If you want your document to be saved as docx
    //Change the file Path here to a path other than your desktop
    Object savePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\YYC\Desktop\TempWord.doc";
    //oWordDoc.Save();
    oWordDoc.SaveAs(ref savePath,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing
       );

    // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
    // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the 
    // correct Close method. 
    object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordDoc);
    // word has to be case to type _Application so that it will find 
    // the correct Quit method. 
    ((Word._Application)oWord).Quit(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);
}
```

Comment: If the code is not breaking out of your ForEach perhaps you would want to refactor the foreach into a for loop and have a loop set on a count < FieldCount then have it break out.. I ran your code without using the foreach and was able to save my template into a word.doc file.. the other changes I added in my answer also worked as to where you have the code in the .Close I got errors with your original code..also I how come the .SaveAs code has comments in the code.. ? was that by mistake..?

Comment: Oups I forgot to uncomment the comments I put in the .SaveAs code. I was testing to see if the errors appear in the .SaveAs

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to do it the other way without accessing the template at all. The code is very ugly without using the template. :( I may go back to the code and try to fix the error.

Comment: I used the same code without a Template the exact code that you had with my changes and it works fine...so I am not sure where you are going wrong..

Comment: Your code works fine as long as I do not save it as docx format.

Comment: yes that's correct.. I thought you were wanting to save it as .doc format.. are you wanting to create and save it as a Template File..? based on the problem in the Title I have corrected your issue...

Comment: I would like to save it as .docx format. But .doc format works fine too. Thanks for your help.